# Error with border-radius in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a simple animation for preloading a web site. It's really simple. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/sqxsf18b/

```
 <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader">

    </div>
 </div>

 #loader-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}


#loader {

    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50em;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #3498db; 
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

#loader:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #e74c3c; 
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

#loader:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #f9c922;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        transform: rotate(0deg);  
    }
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg);  
        -ms-transform: rotate(100deg);  
        transform: rotate(100deg); 
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        transform: rotate(0deg);  
    }
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg);  
        -ms-transform: rotate(100deg);  
        transform: rotate(100deg); 
    }
}
```

It's so weird, in jsfiddle works, but does not on chrome.

the border-radius attribute works on the #loader.before and #loader.after but does not on #loader. I've seen so many solutions but no one worked.
Can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me in Chrome. Can you post more information about the rendering problem you're experiencing?

Also is there a reason you've declared border-radius as `%` on the two inner circles but `em` for the parent?